# I want to reject in-coming call for a particular number but it does not work

Tags: android

I am trying to block incoming call for a particular number. first I try for all incoming call.
it works well.
but when I try for a particular number by the following code the call is not rejected and the phone is ringing ,I tried with my android phone..

```
       @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Log.v(TAG, "Receving....");
      String t1="01741297163",t2="08801741297163";
      TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
      context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  
      try {
       Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
       Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
       m.setAccessible(true);
       Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
       num=b.getString(telephony.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
       if(num.equals(t1)||num.equals(t2)){
       telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
       //telephonyService.silenceRinger();
       telephonyService.endCall();
      } }catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

I do not know the format of incoming number get from the Telephonymanager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;

public class PhoneCallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {    

private Context context;
public PhoneCallStateListener(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {  
SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

switch (state) {

    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:       

      String block_number = prefs.getString("block_number", null);
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
            //Turn ON the mute
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);                 
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
    Toast.makeText(context, "in"+block_number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Class clazz = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    method.setAccessible(true);
    ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);     
    //Checking incoming call number
    System.out.println("Call "+block_number);
    if (incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("+91"+block_number)) {
    //telephonyService.silenceRinger();//Security exception problem
     telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
     telephonyService.silenceRinger();
    System.out.println(" in  "+block_number);
    telephonyService.endCall();
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        //Turn OFF the mute     
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
    break;
    case PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE:
    }
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try printing the incoming phone number in log and then comparing it to the numbers that you have stored? Anyways, the phone numbers that you have stored `t1` and `t2`, do not have std/international codes with them. The correct phone number (if in India) would be

```
t1="+911741297163"
```

as Indias coed is `+91`.

Comment: I try with this "+8801741297163" +88 for country code, but not works, then I take last 11 digit for incoming number and compare without country code, then it works successfully. Why I show the incoming number say please.

Comment: Put Log.v(TAG, "Receving num="+num); and check what is being printed

Answer (score 0):

You should add the country code too with the number. Say +91 for India.Try it!!